# How to do request chaining in Cypress? I am trying to match field from POST response with GET response

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am trying to validate API response from openweatherAPI.

I am doing following steps

1. Create weather station with POST call
2. Get external ID from step#1
3. Match the external ID with GET response and pass the test. If the external ID is not found in GET response fail the test

```
it.only('first POST and array iteration', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/stations?appid=7fe67bf08c80ded756e598d6f8fedaea',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: {
                "external_id": "testweatherapi12",
                "name": "weather_api12",
                "latitude": 35.55,
                "longitude": 89.45,
                "altitude": 56.4
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            cy.log('response is ' + JSON.stringify(res));
            let idIs = res.body.ID;
            cy.log('ID****** is ' + idIs);
            expect(res.status).to.eq(201)

        }).then((res) => {
            cy.request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/stations?appid=7fe67bf08c80ded756e598d6f8fedaea',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then((res) => {
                for (var x = 0; x < res.body.length; x++) {
                    expect(res.body[x].id).to.eq(res.body.ID); //This is failing
                }
            })

        })
    })
```

Comment: Why are you using cypress for that? It's not optimal, I'd use vitest with fetch, no need for a browser here as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am learning Cypress as part of project training

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things I would change:

- in the first `.then(res => )` block, return the `res` - or more precisely `return cy.wrap(res)` since you have a `cy.log()` inside the first `.then(res => )` block and Cypress complains that ***you are mixing asynchronous and synchronous code*** if you don't wrap it.
- also use a different variable name in the second `.then(res => )` block. As it stands, the `expect()` is using just the 2nd `res` and ignoring the first `res`
- use `console.log('response is ', res)` to debug, you will enjoy it more.
- if you put that log in each `.then(res => )` block, you will see the second one is `null` because there is no `return` value.

```js
cy.request({
  ...
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log('response is ', res)
    ...
    return cy.wrap(res)            // <- must pass on the res variable
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('response is ', res)
    cy.request({
      ...
    }).then(res2 => {                             // <- must use a different variable
      for (var x = 0; x < res.body.length; x++) {
        expect(res2.body[0].id).to.eq(res.body.ID)   // This is now passing ✅
      }
    })
  })
```

You have a lot of different ids in the 2nd response, so you probably want this, which gives one result:

```js
const matching = res2.body.filter(item => item.id === res.body.ID)
```

In any case, you can look at both responses in the console and decide what you need to compare.

Comment: Just a small correction. In the loop, we would have to pass "x" instead of "0". I have edited my code. Thanks